# How to know if your cat is pregnant?

Tags: cats, breeding

I wasn't home, so my cousin sent me some photos. When I saw the photos I was shocked and excited at the same time. My cat( female) was mating with another cat ( male of course).There are one-two weeks since that.I think my cat's eyes change when she is hungry. From a dot, it goes like a sharp line.And I think she is eating a little bit more. But she isn't getting fatter or anything.

Comment: Not every mating results in pregnancy. At some point hormone tests may answer the question, but you'd probably have to ask your vet about those. Other than that, it's a matter of waiting for a rapid weight gain in the belly to be obvious, or for her to start obviously looking for a suitable place to have the kittens (which vcan be hard to distinguish from a cat's normal explorations).

Answer (score 1):

Of course the only way to know for sure is to take your kitty to the vet.

However, if your cousin saw the cats mating, there is a very high probability that she is pregnant.   This is because the cat species has a remarkable built in survival mechanism. Unlike humans and many other animals, the female cat does not ovulate until stimulated by the male cat.  This results in most matings becoming a pregnancy.

To directly answer your question, you will likely not see signs of her pregnancy until about 3 weeks after mating.  Here are some signs to look for at that time:

1. Symptoms of being in heat have stopped
2. Her nipples may become pinker and swell
3. She may vomit (similar to human's morning sickness)
4. She may want more attention from you
5. Of course, abdominal enlargement (but you likely won't see this until about the fifth week)
6. Toward the end of her pregnancy, she will show nesting traits.  She will try to find a quiet place to safely deliver her kittens.

Check out the following link to learn more:  http://cats.about.com/od/reproduction/a/pregnant_signs.htm

It's important that you don't let her outside while she is pregnant.   Otherwise, she will find a nesting area outside, and you may never find her again.  Her motherly instinct kicks in, and the safety of her kittens is all she is thinking about.

If she is pregnant, may I suggest spaying her after giving birth, as soon as your vet says you can.  Animal shelters are full of unwanted litters.

I hope this info helps, and I wish you and your kitty the best!

Comment: OK!  I will! She stays on the carpet or on the couch and it's warm and safe there! ( she's not actually my real cat, she stays in my house, actually yard) but thank you!

Comment: Of course, distinguishing when a cat is vomiting from morning sickness from vomiting due to hairballs, or illness, can be difficult.

Comment: @Sara  Awww!   Well, then, thanks for taking care of a stray!

Comment: #2 is the best way to tell (at least with cats that like their tummies rubbed)